# Why does peterson's solution for mutual exclusion require turn == process as condition in while loop?

Tags: c, operating-system

I am trying to understand the solution for the mutual exclusion problem provided by Peterson. So here is Peterson's solution for mutual exclusion:

```
int No_Of_Processes; // Number of processes
int turn; // Whose turn is it?
int interested[No_Of_Processes]; // All values initially FALSE

void enter_region(int process) {
int other; // number of the other process

other = 1 - process; // the opposite process
interested[process] = TRUE; // this process is interested
turn = process; // set flag
while(turn == process && interested[other] == TRUE); // wait
}

void leave_region(int process) {
interested[process] = FALSE; // process leaves critical region
}
```

I don't understand why he uses turn == process in the idle while loop. It looks contradictory since if another process wants to enter the critical region, turn is set to the other process which implies that the previous process can enter the critical region as well disregarding the content of the interested buffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the below sequence of execution to understand why that condition is required:

The "other" process executes the following:

```
interested[other] = TRUE
turn = other
```

At that point the "other" process gets context switched out and the current process in question executes:

```
interested[process] = TRUE
turn = process
```

So at this point we have:

```
interested[other] = TRUE
interested[process] = TRUE
turn = process
```

Under this condition the "other" process will enter the critical section. But this process will not as `(turn == process && interested[other] == TRUE)` will be true. This process will wait until the other process executes `interested[other] = FALSE;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(turn == process && interested[other] == TRUE); // wait
```

is used to wait for the other process which is in the critical section or wants to enter the critical section. Only one process can be in the critical section at any point of time.

All other processes will be in the loop `while(turn == process && interested[other] == TRUE);` while any one process is in the critical section.

When the process in the critical section comes out of the critical section it sets the value of `interested[process]` to `FALSE`, which then makes the condition `turn == process && interested[other] == TRUE` false for current waiting process and the process enter in the critical section.

Answer (score 0):

Neither answer solved my question. I give an explanation. English is not my mother language. We assume there is no `turn` variable.
Two threads may both have executed `interested[process] = TRUE;`. This can happen. For example, T1 is switched out just after executing `interested[process] = TRUE;`. Then T2 executes `interested[process] = TRUE;`, then it comes to the condition `interested[other] == TRUE`, it gets stuck. Then T1 is switched in, it also comes to `interested[other] == TRUE`, it also gets stuck. By adding `turn`, two threads cannot fail at the `interested[other] == TRUE && turn == process` condition at the same time(because `turn` cannot not equal two different values), so deadlock can be avoided.